# Every activity shows its own icon

Tags: android-activity

I have a few activities in my app, but for some reason on the menu there are a lot of

Icons of my app- for every activity.

How can I fix it and make an Icon for MainActivity only?

Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest remove these lines from all Activities except the one you want to open on:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

(I recommend removing them from all the activities exept MainActivity).